# How to send canvas image to email

Tags: jquery, ajax, html5-canvas

I'm trying to send the canvas image to Email.
Firstly I'm capturing div content to canvas using html2canvas.js then I get dataurl now I want to upload that image to the email.

Kindly help me to solve the issue

```
<div class="container">
<p>Some content goes here this content may have stylish text and icons</p>
<p>More contents</p>
</div>
<input type="submit" id="capture_div">
<script>
$(function(){
$('#capture_div').click(function(){
    html2canvas($('.container'), {
     onrendered: function (canvas) {
       var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
       $.ajax({
              type: "post",
              url: "send_mail.php",
              data: {img: canvas.toDataURL("image/png")},
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data) {
              ..................
              },
              error: function () {
              .................
              }
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

I'm now getting the value in send_mail.php

```
<?php
$msg = '<img width="160" height="160" alt="star" src="'.$_POST['img'].'" />';
mail("someone@example.com","My subject",$msg);
?>
```

Comment: ...want to upload that image to the email? don't understand who's email want to upload and when ?

But you can send the dataurl to backend via ajax. just append to the form

Comment: Thank you for the reply I don't want to send the dataurl to email, I need to insert dynamically generated canvas image as message after submit button is clicked.

Comment: You can add an image like this `'<img width="160" height="160" alt="star" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEA....." />`

Comment: no success empty mail.

Comment: Share code to understand better.

Comment: Hi, I update with code kindly check.

Comment: 1st echo the image if you are getting it or not.
if you are getting the image correctly than is fine.
Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php
Also using php mail function doesn't work from local. And even its not reliable to send email. Use sendgrid, mailgun like service which offer free upto 12000 email per month.

Comment: Hi, While I echo the image variable passed from jquery ajax I get like this in console <img src="[removed]iVBORw0KGgo.... />. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Better you use sendgrid, mailgun like service. And check the image is proper or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by save the canvas image to folder and attach to the mail.